# Should I pass Fragment instance or owner returned from getViewLifecycleOwner when calling setLifecycleOwner on data binding

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-databinding

Which approach is correct:

1. Passing `Fragment` instance as `lifecycleOwner`:

   ```
   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
       val binding = FragmentEventSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
       binding.lifecycleOwner = this
       return binding.root
   }
   ```
2. Passing `viewLifecycleOwner` of the `Fragment`:

   ```
   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
       val binding = FragmentEventSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
       binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
       return binding.root
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended solution is to use fragment’s view lifecycle via getViewLifecycleOwner() or getViewLifecycleOwnerLiveData() which were added in Support Library 28.0.0 and AndroidX 1.0.0, so that LiveData will remove observers every time the fragment’s view is destroyed

Reference: [5 common mistakes when using Architecture Components](https://proandroiddev.com/5-common-mistakes-when-using-architecture-components-403e9899f4cb)

Answer (score 0):

The first method is correct.

The second works mostly, but it can implicitly cause your app to crash and it will cost more resources. because `Fragment` implements `LifecycleOwner`, when you can use `this`, your program can compile.

However, when using `this`, the observer last longer. For example, when `onDestroyView()` is executed and `onDestroy()` not, your `RecyclerView` is destroyed, and your LiveData is changed, which will result in your app trying to populate a null `RecyclerView`, and your app will crash.

In Android Studio, if you use `this` it will suggest you using `viewLifecycleOwner`.